# VBA/IE Check the checkbox with same name and different value

Tags: vba, checkbox, io, automation

I would like to check the first checkbox, but my code in VBA does not work.

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="2340">
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="1338">
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="2998">
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="8007">
```

My code to check the first checkbox is:

```
Set Element = objIE.document.getElementsByName("report_filters_product").Value = 2340    
Element.Checked = True
```

But this does not work. What might be going wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (assuming this works just like JavaScript), the period at the start of your first line of VBA code is breaking things. Change that line to `Set Element = document.getElementsByName("report_filters_product").Value = 2340    
` to fix it (if that doesn't work, please tell me)

Comment: It is no a typographical error. My `With objIE` is open.

Comment: And what shows if you press F12 and select the Console tab? Does it show any errors (in red text)?

Comment: No error. It does not check the checkbox.

Comment: The problem is that they have the same name. For example: Checkbox names = checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3...  I could use `Set Element = objIE.document.getElementsByName("checkbox1")(0)
Element.Checked = True` to select the checkbox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the conversation in the chat I noticed what is going wrong in this code. With your first line of code, you're basically selecting an array of all elements with `name="report_filters_product"`. If you want to change the **first** checkbox to be checked, you should first specify that you want to select the first of the element. This can be done as follows:

```
Set Element = objIE.document.getElementsByName("report_filters_product");
Element[0].Checked = True;
```

The key part is the `[0]`, which tells your script to select only the first of the checkboxes.

---

With this code, you're not selecting for which value the checkbox has, but for the index of the checkbox. If you want to select which value the checkbox has, the easiest solution is to give each checkbox an unique `id` attribute, and then select by that. Such a solution would look like this:

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="2340" id="report_2340">
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="1338" id="report_1338">
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="2998" id="report_2998">
<input type="Checkbox" name="report_filters_product" value="8007" id="report_8007">
```

with the script then selecting the item by ID as follows:

```
Set Element = objIE.document.getElementById("report_2340");
Element.Checked = True;
```

Note that in this case, you do *not* need the `[0]`, since `getElementById` *always* returns a single element (because `id` is a unique identifier in a document).

Comment: Thanks, Perfect!      Vba `(0)`

Comment: To give each checkbox an unique `id` should I use `getElementsById` ?

Comment: I've added an extra part to my answer. Did you say that, to select an element (in the first part of my answer) you need `(0)`? If so, I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: No. It is not necessary.